# How to arrange by numeric order highest to lowest from value in [NSMutableDictionary]?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsmutabledictionary

```
var ditto:[NSMutableDictionary] = [["name":"Bob", "rank":14], ["name":"Randy", "rank":5], ["name":"Julie", "rank":20]]
```

How can I sort ditto by numeric order, high to low, according to "rank"? This is the result I want:

```
var ditto:[NSMutableDictionary] = [["name":"Julie", "rank":20],["name":"Bob", "rank":14], ["name":"Randy", "rank":5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code

```
ditto.sortInPlace { ($0.0["rank"] as! Int) > ($0.1["rank"] as! Int) }
```

However you should really use a model value like this

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let rank: Int
}
```

You should also stop using the old fashion way `NSMutableDictionary` and start using the Swift dictionary... you are programming in Swift don't you :)

Comment: doesn't seem to be working, showing the same order afterwards

Comment: @gooberboobbutt: Yes because I used `sort` which returns a new array. I updated my code with `sortInPlace`. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks! I'll select this as the answer once I can. Also I'll check out Swift dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all entries have a "rank" value:

```
 ditto.sortInPlace(){ $0["rank"]! as! Int > $1["rank"]! as! Int }
```